# Determinant of sort of companion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, determinant, companion-matrices

Note: I'm trying no EROs and no induction.

---

This is the matrix I'm given:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
b & 0_F & 0_F & \cdots & 0_F & 0_F & a_1\\ 
-1_F & b & 0_F & \cdots & 0_F & 0_F & a_2\\ 
0 & -1_F & b & \cdots & 0_F & 0_F & a_3\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\ 
0_F & 0_F & \cdots & -1_F &  b & 0_F & a_{n-2}\\ 
0_F & 0_F & \cdots & 0_F &  -1_F & b & a_{n-1}\\ 
0_F & 0_F & \cdots & 0_F & 0_F & -1_F & b+a_n
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is for $b, a_1, ..., a_n \in$ a field $F$ with $b \ne 0_F$ s.t. $A \in F^{n \times n}$. (There's no mention of $n$, but I guess $n \ge 1$.)

1. Looks like this: [Determinant of a companion matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515679/determinant-of-a-companion-matrix) but my method is different because **I plan to not use EROs**.
2. Also looks like this: [Finding determinant for characteristic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338523/finding-determinant-for-characteristic-polynomial) and this: [The characteristic and minimal polynomial of a companion matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/the-characteristic-and-minimal-polynomial-of-a-companion-matrix) but I'm expanding over the last column...but these don't seem to do that.
3. Also looks like transpose of this, but my method is still different. **Maybe I'm doing something wrong if my methods are different from the ones on maths se...**
   [Determinant of companion matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732914/determinant-of-n-times-n-matrix) - Specifically here, someone says in a comment that we're indeed supposed to use induction. I tried but it was very messy with the indices and stuff. Like the minors of $n=k+1$ don't quite match up with the induction hypothesis re $n=k$

Luckily, I'm already given the determinant and just have to prove it. It's not like I have to compute the determinant from scratch. The determinant is given as $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_jb^{j-1} +(b+a_n)b^{n-1}$$ Here $b^0$ makes sense as $b^0=1_F$ because $b \ne 0_F$.

---

**Question 1**: I think I get it for $n \ge 3$, but for $n \le 2$, is the given matrix, and maybe even the given determinant, perhaps kind of ambiguous/not well-defined or something? My concern is that for $n \le 2$, we don't quite have any $0_F$'s.

Based on the given determinant I just guess what the matrix looks like and proceed to compute the determinant.

---

**Question 2**: Is this correct for $n \le 2$?

Case 1: $n=1$. Then $A = [b+a_1]$ and $\det(A)=b+a_1=b^{n}+a_1$.

Case 2: $n=2$. Then $A = \begin{bmatrix}
b & a_1\\ 
-1_F & b+a_2
\end{bmatrix}$. Do cofactor expansion about the 1st row. Then $$\det(A)$$

$$=b(b+a_2)-(a_1)(-1_F)$$
$$=b^2+ba_2+a_1$$
$$=b^n+b^{n-1}a_{n}+a_1$$

---

**Question 3**: Is this correct for $n \ge 3$?

Case 3: $n \ge 3$

Step 1: Do cofactor expansion about the last (nth) column. Then

$$\det(A) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1_F)^{j+n}a_j\det(M_{(j,n)})+(-1_F)^{n+n}(b+a_n)\det(M_{(n,n)})$$

Step 2: Use [the rule that determinant of upper or lower triangular equals product of diagonal entries] to get, for $j=1,...n-1, n$ (I'm including $n$ this time for the index $j$ unlike in Step 1), that $\det(M_{(j,n)}) = b^{j-1}(-1_F)^{n-j}$ because $M_{(j,n)}$ is upper triangular or lower triangular with diagonal entries starting with $j-1$ of $b$'s and then $n-j$ of $-1_F$'s.

Step 3: Therefore, by Steps 1 and 2, we have

$$\det(A) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1_F)^{j+n}a_j\det(M_{(j,n)}) +(-1_F)^{n+n}(b+a_n)\det(M_{(n,n)})$$

$$ = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1_F)^{j+n}a_jb^{j-1}(-1_F)^{n-j} +(-1_F)^{n+n}(b+a_n)b^{n-1}(-1_F)^{n-n}$$

$$ = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1_F)^{j+n+n-j}a_jb^{j-1} +(-1_F)^{n+n+n-n}(b+a_n)b^{n-1}$$

$$ = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1_F)^{2n}a_jb^{j-1} +(-1_F)^{2n}(b+a_n)b^{n-1}$$

$$ = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} a_jb^{j-1} +(b+a_n)b^{n-1}$$

Comment: Technically, you wouldn't change much by multiplying $A$ by $-1$, and even consider working on $\det(-A+bI_n)$ which is nothing but a characteristic polynomial (with $b=\lambda$)...

Comment: @JeanMarie errr....so how would i get $\det A$ from $\det(-A+bI_n)$ ?

Comment: ... by taking $b=0$ and multiplying by $(-1)^n$...

Comment: @JeanMarie is your $b$ different from my $b$ given that for my $b$ we necessarily have my $b \ne 0_F$ ?

Comment: I should have a deeper look. A different hint: your matrix has an Hessenberg form and a Hessenberg matrix is known to possess a factorization as a product of a companion matrix and a triangular matrix. I haven't been able to find a free access document about this property. Here is one which is behind a paywall : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/303532667_Factorization_of_Hessenberg_matrices but with ResearchGate, you can attempt to ask the author to send you a free copy.

Comment: Just found a free access to an article proving this fact in "Factorization of Hessenberg matrices" by John Maroulas, Linear Algebra and its Applications, Volume 506, 1 October 2016, Pages 226-243. Oddly the preceding reference (a Ph. D/ Thesis) is of the same year, the same journal, and the same country...

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks i think but is anything what i did above wrong please?

Comment: A reciprocal question : have you attempted to see this factorization of Hessenberg matrices $H = C T$ into a companion matrix and a triangular matrix, giving $\det(H) = \det(C) \det(T)$.

Comment: You can plainly verify your calculations using excellent @Griboullis general answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie the determinant is given. it's something to prove not something to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

If $R_i$ is the ith row of the determinant, add $R_1/b$ to $R_2$, then $R_2/b$ to $R_3$ etc and finally $R_{n-1}/b$ to $R_n$. It remains a diagonal determinant equal to
\begin{equation}
b^{n-1}\left(b + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_{n-k} b^{-k}\right)
=b^n + \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k b^{k-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: can i do this without EROs?

Comment: thanks for the ERO answer though...but i wish to get the determinant directly

Comment: Elementary row operations are a form of matrix multiplication. Write $A = b I - N + C$ where $N$ is a subdiagonal of $1$s. Then $(b I - N)^{-1} A = I + (b I - N)^{-1}C$ is easily seen to be a diagonal matrix because only the last column of $C$ is non zero. Prove that the $i$-th component of $(b I - N)^{-1}C$ on the last column is $\sum_{k=1}^i (a_k/b^k)$

Comment: I mean $\sum_{k=1}^i(a_k/b^{i+1-k})$

Comment: wrong/unclear question. i mean: can i just do the cofactor thing in OP instead of doing EROs?

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie but i don't wanna use EROs...